# ffmpeg: append JPEG frames to the end of video

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation, slideshow

I need to append JPEG images to the end of existing video file using ffmpeg tool.
Input images have same resolution as the video. No audio streams. As far as I understood from the documentation, it is possible with using a complex filter. Please help me to do it.

For example I have:
Input image: frame0.jpg
Input video: slideshow.avi; fps: 1
Expected output video: out.avi

And what about allocated virtual memory? Does the output format affect required size of the RAM buffer for concatenation process? For example if the video size is 1GB and output format is standard .avi, will it be loaded into RAM 1GB buffer entirely while processing? What output format should I use to reduce RAM usage? Is .flv more suitable?

Comment: What's the codec of the avi video stream?

Comment: It is just standard codec: `ffmpeg -i slide01.jpg -r 1 slideshow.avi`

Answer (score 3):

1.
from image.Jpg to Image.avi
(5 sec duration and size "-s 384x288" must be the same of avi video size)

```
 ffmpeg.exe -loop 1 -i image.jpg -t 5 -s 384x288 -y image.avi
```

2.
Concatenate two file

```
ffmpeg.exe -i sample.avi -i image.avi -filter_complex "[0:v:0][1:v:0]concat=n=2:v=1[outv]" -map "[outv]" -y output.avi
```

Comment: Thank you for response. As I understood there is no way to append frame (in image format) directly to the video. First, we need to convert frame into small one-frame-video and only then we can concatenate it.

Comment: Correct, It's the only way with ffmpeg